# Create a GNOME shell extension that enables and disables the webcam

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, go, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I would like to create a shell extension for Ubuntu 20.04 that enables and disables the webcam but I don't know absolutely anything about JavaScript. Although, the extension is pretty simple: I would like to make a simple camera icon in the top bar that

1. When clicked on just becomes crossed out and executes `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`, to disable the webcam.
2. When then re-clicked on just runs `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` and the icon returns to the one before, enabling the webcam.

How can I do it?

EDIT: I made it by myself in GO, if you're searching for it here it is https://github.com/0xfederama/simple-tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably start by looking through the tutorial on the GNOME Wiki:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing

When spawning your command, you're probably going to want to use `pkexec` instead of `sudo`. I wouldn't recommend doing anything requiring superuser access in an extension, but `pkexec` will at least work properly in a GUI environment.

To spawn your command, you can probably get away with [`GLib.spawn_command_line_async()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/glib20/glib.spawn_command_line_async), although I always prefer [`GSubprocess`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gio20/gio.subprocess) myself.